# AVR assembly, incrementing and decrementing values from data memory

Tags: assembly, avr

So I was giving a project to write a program that stores a value in a data memory location, `0x200`, the program then decrements the value and stores it the next memory location. I just started assembly programming and I tend to write it with the mentality of writing with a high level language.
Here's the code I created (it looks a lot but that's just cause of comments):

```
.cseg
.org 0x200 ;Trying to get the program to start assemblimg from memory location, 0x200

.DSEG
store: .BYTE 1 ;Trying to "create a variable called store to represent memory location, 0x200"

.CSEG
    lds r17, store ;loading variable store into registry 17

.def count = r16
    ldi count, 0x04 ;the first value, 0x04 assigned to variable, count and stored in registry 16


lp: 

    sts store, r16 ;stores value in r16, i.e. 0x04, into store which should point to memory location 0x200

    cpi count, 0x00 ;check if value is zero yet

    breq done ;if value is zero end program

    dec count ;decrement the value of count, i.e. 0x04

    inc r17 ;increment content of r17, which is store which refers to memory locaion, 0x200

    rjmp lp ;restart loop


done: jmp done ;end of program
```

I know it's a bit messy cause of the comments, sorry for that
If it helps this was the first code I tried but r15 doesn't work with sts:

```
.cseg
.org 0

lds r15, 0x200
lds r17, 0x001

.def count = r16
    ldi count, 0x04


lp:
    sts r15, r16
    cpi count, 0x00
     done
    dec count
    ADD r15, r17
    rjmp lp

done: jmp done
```

Comment: Note your `.org` directives are kind of messed up - you seem to assume they are valid globally for every segment. That is not true. You currently only put code to 200h - .dseg has no .org, so your data will be put starting from address 0 (unless you have a linker script that puts stuff into the right places). AVR is based on *Harvard architecture* so code and data have two different address spaces.

Comment: @tofro so how would I get around having dseg start assembling from 0x200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `STS k,Rr`: Stores one byte from a Register to the data space. For
>   parts with SRAM, the data space consists of the Register File, I/O
>   memory, and internal SRAM (and external SRAM if applicable).
>
> `ST Z, Rr`,`ST Z+, Rr`,`ST -Z, Rr`,`STD Z+q, Rr`: Stores one byte
>   indirect with or without displacement from a register to data space.
>   For parts with SRAM, the data space consists of the Register File, I/O
>   memory, and internal SRAM (and external SRAM if applicable).

You need to use `ST` instruction and one of the pointer registers (X, Y, and Z) to store one byte from a register to special RAM address.

Like this :

```
.def count = r16
.equ array_size = 5

.dseg
.org    0x200
array_region: .BYTE array_size

.cseg
.org    0

; Vector Table ( Offset 0 -> Rest )
JMP start



.org    INT_VECTORS_SIZE*2 ; Here is end of vector table
RJMP    start
.include "m32def.inc" ; We should specify a special AVR for using its definitions

; Start From Here
 start:

; Initializing Stack Pointer ( to the end of RAM ). You must do it for returning from subroutines and Interrupts.
;LDI        R16,LOW(RAMEND)
;LDI        R17,HIGH(RAMEND)
;OUT        SPL,R16
;OUT        SPH,R17


LDI XL, LOW(array_region) ; Low byte of X
LDI XH, HIGH(array_region) ; High byte of X

LDI count, array_size

lp:
ST X+, R16
DEC count
BREQ done ; 'DEC' instruction will effect on Z flag.
RJMP lp

done: JMP done
```

Note that pointer registers are equal to the R26 to R31 registers ([R27:R26] => X , [R29:R28] => Y , [R31:R30] => Z).

Comment: I'm really confused now. I understand that `ST X+, R16` stores count from R16 to X, while X+ moves to the next data memory location after each loop, right? But what exactly does the `ADD R15, R17` do? And how is `R15` linked to X, it only shows up once.

Comment: As for everything between `start:`  and `lp:` , I think I'll have to buy and read a book on this to understand it.

Comment: @DrewU I am sorry. `ADD R15, R17` was left from the previous code! َ َAlso , You're quite right about `ST X+, R16` and `X`

Comment: Okay Thank you, Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure what the question is, but I will try to help.

```
STS k, Rd        ; stores Rd to address k.
```

STS is known as Direct Data Addressing, which requires a constant to store the data in. Using STS would require us to hardcode every single store, which is not exactly a good solution. What you need is Indirect Data  Addressing, ST.

X, Y, and Z are pointer registers, which can be used to point to specific addresses.

```
ST Y+, R16
```

The above code will store what is in R16 into address Y, then increment Y by one.

In your example, you called .org 0 in .cseg. What this would do is make the starting address (origin) to store at 0x00 for program memory. To set the origin in data memory to 0x200, you need to call .org 0x200 in .dseg.

I made this from the code you gave, just tweaked it a little. It should work.

```
.dseg
.org 0x200
```

Example:

```
.dseg               ;Data segment
.org 0x200          ;Start storing at 0x200
storage: .byte 1    ;Allocate 1 byte for storage

.cseg                  ;Code segment
ldi yH, high(storage)  ;storage <== Y
ldi yL, low(storage)
ldi r16, 0x2B          ;Load r16 with 0x2B

loop:
    st Y+, r16     ;Address Y <== r16, increments Y by 1.
    cpi r16, 0x00  ;Compare r16 to 0.
    breq end       ;If zero status bit is 1, branch to end.
    dec r16        ;Otherwise, decrement and loop.
    rjmp loop

end:               ;End loop
    jmp end
```

Check your AVR Assembly Instruction Set. ST allows you to store and pre-Increment/Decrement, or post-Increment/Decrement values in X, Y, or Z. Point is, if you want to store things from registers in consecutive data memory locations, use:

```
ST X, Rd
```

Comment: Hey, I actually had to change my code cause there was an update with our project and it kinda matches yours, except I used Z which refered to the constant `0x4f`which was then loaded into `r16`as per given instructions. I wanted to ask, assuming you had a variable "result" that refers to the data memory location 0x200....how would you get it to increment to the next location in a loop

Comment: imply put, I had to replace `Y+` with result which points to `0x200`but I don't know how to get it to increment

Comment: It's just syntax. `X`, `Y`, and `Z` refer to their respective pointer address. You cant replace that field with a constant or other register. Some way or another you need to load that number into a pointer register. Store, then increment what is in that register before looping from your description. If you need more info 

[here's the manual page](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_ST.html) on the ST instruction